# Email attachments and bandwidth usage

Tags: email, attachment, email-attachments, mass-emails, bulk-email

I am working on a module that enables our system users to send bulk emails to all the registered active applicants from the applicant pool. Currently, there are more than 10 million active applicants in the pool to which emails can be sent. I am thinking to create blocks of emails and wait for a few minutes before sending individual blocks. What I am more concerned about is the attachment.

Since every email can contain an attachment(max. 2MB), There is a possibility that a huge amount of bandwidth will be consumed, even if the email is sent to only 10,000 applicants (2MB X 10,000 applicants = 20GB bandwidth approximately). My questions are:

1. Since every attachment is a MIME type, will the size of the email be calculated the   the way I have calculated above? Or there is a different mechanism specially in context of bandwidth usage?
2. In your opinion, what options do I have If I have to send a document to thousands of people and want to save the bandwidth as well? I can put the document on the server and let everybody download, but will it not consume the some amount of bandwidth? (I don't want to go down the FTP route)
3. Somebody was saying moving these kinds of documents to the cloud?? Does cloud technology offer solutions that cater for this kind of need?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The attachment creates a problem of being flagged as spam. Best avoid it if you can.

The attachment is MIME encoded rather than gzip compressed. This takes up 1.5 times the bandwidth.

It is not easy to see if the attachment has been opened unless it has some payload that does that for you - again this could be flagged as spam.

Putting these documents on a regular web server will make sense. You can use normal Google Analytics to see what is going on. You can also use public caching to make sure that the document is cached by ISPs etc, thereby reducing your download. The document can also be compressed with gzip to be opened with a browser, unobtrusively doing the un-compressing for your recipients.